# how to transform categorical dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is below

```
Sex type 
M    A  
W    B
W    A
M    C
```

I would like to get below result

```
M W A B C
1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
```

I tried

`df['Sex','type'].get_dummies()`

But didnt work well.

how can I get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems you need [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
print (pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix=''))
   M  W  A  B  C
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0
2  0  1  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  1
```

Also if some duplicates in columns names is necessary `groupby` by columns `axis=1` and `level=0` and aggregate `max`:

```
print (pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='', prefix='').groupby(axis=1, level=0).max())
   A  B  C  M  W
0  1  0  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0  0  1
3  0  0  1  1  0
```